# JavaScript is retrieving data from mysql database that is suppose to be deleted with AJAX delete method already

Tags: javascript, mysql, ajax

In the script , a button have an onclick function that call deleteByName function

```
<button onclick='deleteByName("name","view","view_value")' type='button'>
```

In this function , it use AJAX to execute delete method and calls search function to update page

```
function deleteByName (target,view,view_value){
    var url = "http://localhost/assignment_web/index.php/facility/name/"+target;
    request.open("DELETE", url, true);
    request.send(null); 
    search("all");
}
```

In search function , it use AJAX get method to retrieve data and use updatePage attribute to update the innerHTML

```
function search(type) {
    var target = "" ; 
    if(type=="district"|type=="name"){
        var target = document.getElementById('option_txt').value;
    }
    var url = "http://localhost/assignment_web/index.php/facility/"+type+"/"+target;
    request.open("GET", url, true);
    request.onreadystatechange = updatePage;
    request.send(null);
}

function updatePage() {
    if (request.readyState==4) {
        if (request.status==200) {
            var serverData = request.responseText;
            console.log("serverData: "+serverData);
            var dataArr = JSON.parse(serverData);
            var objLen = Object.keys(dataArr).length;
            var view = document.querySelector('input[name="option"]:checked').value;
            var view_value; 
            var html ="<ul>";
            for(let i=0;i<objLen;i++){
                var name =dataArr[i].Name_en ; 
                if(view=="district"){view_value = dataArr[i].District_en;}else if(view=="name"){view_value = dataArr[i].Name_en;
                }else{view_value = "all" ; }
                html = html+"<li>District : "+dataArr[i].District_cn+"&nbsp"+dataArr[i].District_en
                        +"</li>...<li><button onclick='deleteByName(\""+name+"\",\""+view+"\",\""+view_value+"\")' type='button'>delete</button>
                        <div name=\""+name+"_textBox\" id=\""+name+"_textBox\"></div></li><hr>" ;
            }   
            html = html+"</ul>";
            document.getElementById("displayArea").innerHTML = html;
        }
    }
}
```

The question is , in get method , it retrieved the data (shown in `console.log(DataArr)` ) i was deleted from the delete method before . How do i make sure the update function won't retrieve any data that is deleted before instead retrieving the data after the delete method is complete ...

Comment: Obvious question: are you sure that your server is actually deleting the data?

Comment: Yes it is deleted , the data is not retrieved anymore the second time i click the button .

Comment: But the problem is at the first time I click the button , it still retrieve the data that is supposed to be deleted .

Comment: I think it has something to do with the function position ? I guess ? Like out of function , inside the function thing ?